# How to deform a surface 3-dimensionally with two curves

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I was trying now for a few hours, no chance. As seen on the screenshot, I want to deform that triangle 3-dimensionally so that it looks a bit like a tent. The red marked edge and vertex on the opposing side (the anchors) have to stay right in place because I apply other modifiers in the next steps. I too apply the Mirror Modifier which is active on that screenshot.

I want to deform it as follows: the orange edge has to be deformed on the "Z" and "Y" coordinates to get the shape a little bit like the yellow curve. Same with the turquoise edge to its corresponding curve on the "X" and "Y" axis. The rest of the vertices have to follow proportionally. *Well... I tried it manually by proportional editing, but that would be very difficult to achieve what I want.*

[image]

EDIT: I edited my question so it would be understandable without a picture.

Comment: With a simple shape like that, couldn't you start the modeling process with the curves that you want and bridge the loops?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. That would be an option but didn't try it yet because I assume that the surface would still be (almost) flat and 2.) as far as I know, two different curves produce two different amounts of vertices, so I would have to tinker. I imagine there is a lazy/pro way I would like to get to know. EDIT: Also I apply 4 other modifiers on top of that, so with that imagined way I would still have control over the result.

Comment: Do you have an end-goal reference image that you could add?

Comment: Yes, here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185584/realizing-ornaments-with-more-than-one-curve-modifier?noredirect=1#comment310936_185584. I have everything of that ornament done except the defoeming of the end cap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a triangle with one straight edge, two concave edges, and a concave bridge between them.

Let's start by making a triangle out of a plane like this:
[image: Triangle]

Then delete only the face by selecting everything and pressing <kbd>**X**</kbd>, <kbd>**N**</kbd>.
[image: Deleted Face]

Subdivide all three edges with 2 cuts and extrude and scale inward about this far.
[image: Extrude edges inward]

Using individual origins (<kbd>**.**</kbd> for pie menu), scale the edges up until the corners are close enough to merge.
[image: touch corners]

Press <kbd>**M**</kbd> and merge by distance. Increase the distance until the message at the bottom shows 3 vertices have been removed.
[image: merged 3]

Select everything and fill with <kbd>**F**</kbd>.
[image: face fill]

Add a subsurf.

Holding <kbd>**Alt**</kbd>, click twice on a boundary edge to select the whole boundary. You can then set the edge creases to `1` with <kbd>**Shft**</kbd><kbd>**E**</kbd>.

Tweak the vertices to your liking and you will get something like this:
[image: final]

If the normals are flipped, in edit mode, just press <kbd>**Shft**</kbd><kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd><kbd>**N**</kbd> to calculate the normals to face opposite the "normal" direction (since the mesh is concave).

Comment: Can I get yet some concave curves into that surface?

Comment: Well this answer was very helpful, thanks a lot! You literally saved my day. My model looks good, nontheless it would be nice to know how to make said tent and deform 3-dimensionally.

Comment: Like have the bottom edge curve inward?

Comment: No but like bending the straight edges (except the bottom one) inward, to get a dent (maybe and also) according to the two curvatures. I would prefer and I think it is better to do it as a subsequent step after all the steps you described, because I don't want to change the curvatures anymore, because they look good.

Comment: Got ya, a change like that would be done best with different topology though. It's pretty tricky sometimes to get nice curvature on 3 sided surfaces. (Although, I may be too much of a perfectionist since I'm into modeling cars.)

Comment: There's so much character in curves. What does different topology mean?

Comment: Basically, a different structure of polygons across the surface. Like ico sphere vs UV sphere. Not necessarily quads vs tris though. Quads are usually better.

Comment: Ok so I have to loop cut the edges, and then?

Comment: Edited answer. It should have really nice looking curvature with the new topology.